# Is col sampling in GBM/XGB bias the variable importance?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, boosting, importance

*GBM: Ensemble models like GBM, Light GBM or XGBoost*

Importance indicates how useful each feature was in the construction of the boosted decision trees within the model. The more an attribute is used to make key decisions with decision trees, the higher its relative importance be it split or gain.

**Now with the restriction in feature passed at each tree by setting colsample_bytree < 1, is it safe to assume that this will bias the variable importance?**

I understand the concept of overfitting and have restricted num leaf and the depth of trees. Currently, of 50 features,  10-12 features are used for a split in each tree. But at each tree, all 50 features are passed.

Is it worthy to use colsample_bytree if feature selection based on importance is the objective of model fit?

Appreciate you time.

Comment: @Xi'an   Any thoughts?

Comment: @Mark White  Any insight please

Comment: @Matthew Drury  what is your take on bias due to random sampling